# Treetop infinite recursion with negative rule

Tags: ruby, treetop

I have the following treetop grammar:

```
grammar TestGrammar

    rule body
        text / expression
    end 

    rule text
        not_delimiter*
    end 

    rule expression
        delimiter text delimiter
    end 

    rule delimiter
        '$' 
    end 

    rule not_delimiter
        !delimiter
    end 

end
```

When I try to parse an expression, eg 'hello world $test$', the script goes in an infinite loop.
The problem seems to come from the not_delimiter rule, as when I remove it the expression get parsed.

What is the problem with this grammar?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your expected output, and what's the output when you remove `not_delimiter`?  Also, why should this string parse?  "hello world $test$" is neither a text (sequence of non $'s), nor an expression (text which starts and ends with $).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be where you are attempting to match:

```
rule text
    not_delimiter*
end
```

Since the `*` will also match nothing you have the possibility of matching `[^$]*`, which I think is what is causing the infinite loop.

Also, you need to match multiple `bodies` at the starting rule, otherwise it will return `nil`, since you will only ever match either a `text` rule or an `expression` rule but not both.

```
rule bodies
   body+
end
```

This will parse:

```
require 'treetop'
Treetop.load_from_string DATA.read

parser = TestGrammarParser.new

p parser.parse "hello world $test$"

__END__
grammar TestGrammar
   rule bodies
      body+
   end
   rule body
      expression / text
   end
   rule expression
      delimiter text delimiter
   end
   rule text
      not_delimiter+
   end
   rule not_delimiter
      [^$]
   end
   rule delimiter
      '$'
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! indeed, that make sense. I really wish treetop had a better documentation and error output, debugging can sometimes get troublesome.